# Forward declaration of struct

Tags: c++

I have a header file a.h and inside that I have declared one structure. The name of that structure is `file`. Inside `file` I have 3 members: a, b, c. In a.cpp I have implemented that structure and assigned some values to that structure variable.

Now I have another file b.h. Inside it I have a forward declaration of the structure `file`. Until this point if I compile it's not showing an error but when I am going to access the variable present in that structure through that b.cpp class it will give an error like "undefined struct".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please rephrase the question to use capital letters at the end of sentence, otherwise it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **What is the root cause of error?**

When you Forward declare a type, the compiler treats it as an **Incomplete type**.

The forward declaration tells the compiler that the said type exists and nothing more about the particular type.So, You cannot perform any action(*like creating objects, or dereferencing pointers to that type*) on that type which needs compiler to know its memory layout.

> **Solution:**

You cannot forward declare if you need to deference the structure members, You will need to include the header file in the source file.This would ensure that the compiler *knows* the memory layout of the type. You will have to design your project accordingly.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that incomplete types are sometimes used for encapsulation of APIs. They effectively force the user to only access the structure via the exposed API functions. So, an alternative might be for him to add needed API functions instead of directly accessing the members.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: Well said.That is indeed true.But it depends on the *intent*, *purpose* & finally the *design*.We don't know either of them since OP choose abstract names like `A`, `B` and so on..

Comment: then what about the forward declaration of the class ?
how the compiler knows about the memory layout in this case ?

Comment: @vivek: It doesn't, until it sees the class definition. That's only a problem for a compiler if you try to use the class between the forward declaration and the definition.

Answer (score 13):

To access members, a full definition is required. You need to `include` the header inside `b.cpp`, not just forward-declare the `struct` (which yields an incomplete type).

EDIT:

A forward declarations is enough for:

```
class B;
class C
{
    B& b;
    B* b;
    B foo();
    foo(B b);
};
```

but not for

```
class B;
class C
{
    B b;   //ERROR
    B foo()
    {
        B x; //error
        x.whatever(); //error
        return B(); //error
    }
};
```

Comment: then what about the forward declaration of the class ? how the compiler knows about the memory layout in this case

Comment: @vivek it doesn't need to. If you only have references or pointers, or use the class as a return type or pass it as a parameter, it doesn't need to know the full definition.

Comment: thankx for the reply brother ..
so you are saying the compiler search for the full defination only if you are going for a forward declaration of the structure. and for class it knows automatically ??

Comment: @vivek no, it has nothing to do with class or struct.

Comment: but without including the header file we can go for the forward declaration of the class and use it's memebers ? this is the place i am getting the doubt .i am using the struct , the same way i go for the forward declaration of the class

Comment: @vivek you can't use members with just a forward declaration. Those are the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the definition of your struct where the members are used or the compiler doesn't know what they are.

so if you have in b.cpp, this

```
   func(mystruct &s)
   {
        s.a = 1;
   }
```

The compiler is fine until it gets to the assignment. At which point, it tries to find the definition of 'a' inside 'mystruct', and can't find it.

You should  `#include "a.h"` in b.cpp, or possibly, depending on what else is in a.h, you might want a separate header for the structure and include that.

Comment: then what about the forward declaration of the class ? here we dont have to include the header file for the respective class ??

Comment: i didn't say alter b.h, I said alter b.cpp. You can use a forward declaration where the compiler doesn't need to know anything about the contents of the structure, but when you are accessing the contents, it clearly does need this information.